# Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages -bluez:i386 conflicts bluez-alsa:i386

Tags: android, ubuntu, x86, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install ia32-lib by entering the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

for android os but can not be installed correctly

and shows the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I add the ia32-libs-multiarch before ia32-libs due to dependency as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch ia32-libs
```

the same problems again to be happened ia32 -libs-mlutiarch:i386 which depends on

bluez-alsa:i386 .............

Finally, I run the final commands:

sudo apt-get install bluez:i386 bluez-alsa:i386 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 ia32-libs

which shows the following messages:

```
bluez:i386 is already the neweset version(5.37-0ubuntu5).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an 
impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
bluez:i386 : Conflicts: bluez-alsa:i386 but 4.101-0ubuntu8b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, What does the above message means ? Shall I need to remove the previous bluez:i386 due to the conflict with bluez-alsa:i386 ? How can I fix this problem?